# How to move instance properties to instance initialization in IDE?

Tags: python, initialization, pycharm

I start learning Python and some things are not clear for me.

In Kivy framework I do ui button like this:

```
btn = Button(text= 'I am a Button',
            font_size = 16,
            background_color=[1, 0, 0, 1]
            )
```

if I write like this

```
btn = Button()
btn.text= 'I am a Button'
btn.font_size = 16
btn.background_color=[1, 0, 0, 1]
```

everything works fine too.

Is there any critical difference in this descriptions of the instances, besides to the fact that the second takes more lines and uses more calls and can affect the performance?

I also wanted to know if there is a way to automatically (refactoring?) in IDE (I use PyCharm) to convert one way to another? Because the second looks more convenient for me, as for a beginner, because of autocompletion, but the first looks like more correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned both approaches are working fine since are the same thing.

In the first approach you are overloading the class "Button" with initial values while instantiating the class at the same time.

In your second approach you are instantiating the class "Button" without initial values (so the class default values will be used). After that you call the class and set the values of the class manually which leads to the same result as the first approach.

PyCharm can do many things but I don't know of a command to do what you want, sorry.